# Showing or refuting that $f:X\to X$ injective implies epijective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $f:X\to X$ is an a injective function and $X$ set, does this implies that $f$ epijective?

I have that:

$f$ injective implies there exists $g:X\to X$ left inverse to $f$, $gf(x)=x$ for all $x$. Now, let $y\in X$, $f(y)=x$ some $x\in X$, then $gf(y)=g(x)$, therefore $y=g(x)$ but $g$ is not $f$...
The sentence is true?

Comment: Assuming that "epijective" means "surjective", it's not true. Consider $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x) = 2x$.

Comment: only if $X$ is a finite set :)

Answer (score 2):

What you have shown is that $g(x)$ is surjective, which isn't much of a surprise, as $f(x)$ is a right inverse to it. You have not shown that $f(x)$ is surjective, which you won't be able to do, as $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x) = 2x$ is an injection from a set to itself that is not surjective.